# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linker-scripts

I have a problem I need help with.
I am currently trying to write a program to read out the address of a section I created.

**add.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned char arduino_handler_size[];

int main(){
    printf("section `.arduino_handler` starts at %p and the 1st byte is %x\n",
    arduino_handler_size, (unsigned int)arduino_handler_size[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

**arduino_handler.ld**:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
ENTRY(main)
OUTPUT(Test)

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text) }
    . = ALIGN(0x1000);
    .data : { *(.data) }
    . = ALIGN(0x10000);
    .bss : { *(.bss)} 
    . = ALIGN(0X10000);
    .arduino_handler :
    {
    arduino_handler_size = 0x10;
    arduino_handler_start = .;
    . = . + arduino_handler_size;
    arduino_handler_end = .;
    }
}
```

When I run `gcc -T arduino_handler.ld -N add.c` I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am working on:
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64

I have tried changing the gcc version from 7 to 4.8 and back to 8. That sadly doesn't help.
The symbolic link for libgcc_s is not broken, but it still gives me an error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure elf64-x86-64 is the correct OUTPUT_FORMAT?

Comment: Which other 64 formats could I use?

Comment: It would help if you could describe what you are intending to do. Apparently, you are trying to link a Linux dynamic executable using an (somewhat oversimplified) linker script?

Comment: I'm trying to create a section explicitly using a linkerscript. Then I want to get the address of the section and print it out with the executable.

Comment: if you link using a linker script through a `-T` argument, you'll loose your original linker script (that's required to build a valid Linux executable). If you leave the `-T` command line switch away and just mention the linker script on the command line (as you would do with an object file), it's contents will be added to the default linker script.

Comment: When I do that, the compiler tells me that I forgot to put the `-T` option. So it doesn't compile without it.